# How to trigger a task on completion of two other tasks in Airflow DAG in python?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I have a scenario like the one below. `Task 3` should be triggered on successful completion of `Task1` and `Task2`. I have shared my code below, can you let me know what is missing in it for the scenario?

[image]

**My code**

```
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.contrib.sensors.aws_glue_catalog_partition_sensor import AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from utils import FAILURE_EMAILS

yesterday = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email': FAILURE_EMAILS,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('trigger_job', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

wait_for_task1 = AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor(
    task_id='Task1',
    database_name='db',
    table_name='table1',
    expression='load_date={{ ds_nodash }}',
    timeout=60,
    dag=dag)

wait_for_task2 = AwsGlueCatalogPartitionSensor(
    task_id='Task2',
    database_name='db',
    table_name='table2',
    expression='load_date={{ ds_nodash }}',
    timeout=60,
    dag=dag)

execute_sql = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='Task3',
    postgres_conn_id='REDSHIFT_CONN',
    sql="schema_do_lines.sql",
    params={'limit': '50'},
    dag=dag
)

execute_sql.set_upstream(wait_for_task1)
```

How can this be done in airflow using python?

Answer (score 3):

You need <s>two</s> *one* simple thing:

1. Set the dependencies right. For now you have coded that `execute_sql` depends on `wait_for_task1`. You have to specify that `execute_sql` also depends on `wait_for_task2` by adding the line `execute_sql.set_upstream(wait_for_task2)` at the end of your code.
2. BONUS: You may have to set the `trigger_rule` parameter in your task definition. You can read more about it in [this documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules). **In your specific case there is no need to set it explicitly** because by default it is set on `all_success` (i.e. execute task only if all the parents have succeeded), and thus `execute_sql` will only trigger when both tasks it depends on have succeeded.